# ReadAllText method appends file path to the application path

Tags: c#

I am using ReadAllText method to read file contents into a string but I keep getting an exception file not found. That happened because, for some reason, ReadAllText appends file path to the application path and attempts to find it:

> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\Projects\MyApp1\MyApp1\bin\Debug\C\Test\MyFile.csv'.

```
string FileName ="C:\Test\MyFile.csv";
string allText = File.ReadAllText(fileName, encoding);
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The correct initialization of your filename is string _FileName =@"C:\Test\MyFile.csv";_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# you need to escape the `\` character when you have enclosed it in a string that is enclosed in quotes.  Escaping is needed because the `\` character is treated as a way of displaying special characters in a text string. Change the code to the following:

```
string FileName ="C\\Test\\MyFile.csv";
string allText = File.ReadAllText(fileName, encoding);
```

You could also use the special `@` operator to specify a verbatim string literal. That would look like the following following:

```
string FileName =@"C\Test\MyFile.csv";
string allText = File.ReadAllText(fileName, encoding);
```

**Finally**, You are missing the `:` character in your path. The code should actually look like the following:

```
string FileName = @"C:\Test\MyFile.csv";
string allText = File.ReadAllText(fileName, encoding);
```

Comment: My bad, I missed ":"! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `:` in filename, thus it looks like relative path for `File.ReadAllText` method, so it appends this to the path where executable file is located. Also `\` symbols should be escaped in the string.

Just change it to

```
string FileName =@"C:\Test\MyFile.csv";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `FileName` is off. First, you're missing a colon between drive name and forward slash; it should be `C:\`. Second, you should be properly escaping the `\` character, like this: `C:\\Test\\...` (or, using [verbatim strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx), `@"C:\Test\..."`)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `C\` should be `C:\`.  Also you need to escape your slashes:

```
"C:\\Test\\MyFile.csv"
```

or make the whole string a literal:

```
@"C:\Test\MyFile.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code as below-

```
string FileName = @"C:\Test\MyFile.csv";
```